# removing "acceleration" from subtitle files

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, math

I have a video with subtitles (and corresponding timestamps) in a MySQL database. Sometimes the timestamp on the video and subtitle syncs, sometimes it doesn't.

The problem is that it's not a consistent offset within the video (i.e. the difference is increasing throughout the video so using a simple UPDATE didn't work: `"UPDATE subtitles SET Timestamp=Timestamp+$time WHERE title=$video";'`)

How do I write a PHP script to calculate the "acceleration" of the offset and then update several hundred MySQL entries for that video?

Comment: What type of field is Timestamp, am I correct in assuming it's the number of seconds after the beginning of the video?

Comment: timestamp counts seconds or microseconds?

Comment: number of seconds since the beginning, in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a bunch of rows in the subtitles table with Timestamp values that need to be individually adjusted.  This is a guess, but it sounds like you need to change the Timestamp values in a way like this:

```
0.0   -->  0.0
1.0   -->  1.1
2.0   -->  2.2
```

For this example the formula is

```
newTimestamp[row n] = Timestamp[row 0] + 
                       (Timestamp[row n] - Timestamp[row 0]) * factor)
```

The factor in this example is 1.1, which will speed up your subtitles by 10%.

Your question asks for an algorithm to determine the correct factor to use.  I am sorry that I can't suggest a way to do that without knowing a lot more about how you store your video.

You then ask for an algorithm to apply the factor to your Timestamp values in the rows of your table.  What you had is very close.  Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE `subtitles` 
   SET `Timestamp`=
          MIN(`Timestamp`) + ( $factor * (`Timestamp` - MIN(`Timestamp`) )
 WHERE title=$video
```

The trouble is, DATETIME values don't really work with arithmetic.  So we need to muck about a bit more to get this to go.  We need the time difference in as a number, like so.

```
          ROUND (
           ((       HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`))) * 3600.0) +
            (     MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`))) * 60.0  ) +
            (     SECOND(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`)))         )
           ) * 1000000.0 +
           (MICROSECOND(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`)))          ) 
          )
```

This hairy expression turns the difference between the current time and the first time into an integer number of microseconds.

Then we need to apply the factor and add it back to the beginning time using the kind of time arithmetic that does work:  `timeval = othertimeval + INTERVAL ROUND(xx * factor) MICROSECOND`.

```
UPDATE `subtitles` 
   SET `Timestamp`=
          MIN(`Timestamp`) + INTERVAL 
          ROUND ((
           ((       HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`))) * 3600.0) +
            (     MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`))) * 60.0  ) +
            (     SECOND(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`)))         )
           ) * 1000000.0 +
           (MICROSECOND(TIMEDIFF(`Timestamp`,MIN(`Timestamp`)))          ) 
          ) * $factor) MICROSECOND
 WHERE title=$video
```

Again, there's some guesswork in this example, but this kind of thing should work.

Are we having fun yet?  Are we? Are we?

Comment: Holy explanation Batman! Thanks Ollie! How do I calculate $factor though? For example, if the line "Stackoverflow rocks" happens 62 seconds into the video, but the subtitle file says it happens at 74 seconds in, and then "Answered question" happens at 210 seconds but the subtitle file says it happens 525 seconds in, then how do I figure that out? 12 second difference 62 seconds in and 315 second difference 210 seconds in (and there is 0 difference at 0 seconds), how do I figure that out? Is is `{[(315-210)-(74-62)]/(210-62)}`?

Comment: This approach of using a time-dilation factor made the assumption that the subtitle track could be brought into sync with the video track by speeding it up or slowing it down a certain constant percentage.  The examples you show:  74 : 62 and 525 : 210  (subtitles : video) show that a constant time-dilation factor isn't going to work. I think you have ahead of you the painstaking job of figuring out the actual moment-in-time for each subtitle.

Comment: alright, thanks anyway Ollie. I appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but its better than never :)

You can use library.
For example your video length is 1 hour. And your subtitles at the beginning are in sync. And at the end of video subtitles are 10 seconds in front of video. So you need to subtract -10 seconds from the end. -5 seconds from the middle... and so on...

```
$subtitles = Subtitles::load('subtitles.srt'); // you can also manually add subtitles from DB using ->add(...) method
$subtitles->shiftTimeGradually(-10);
$subtitles->save('synced-subtitles.srt');
```

https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles